# PRISMA 2.0 - I need help to delete a record inside a field with relationship list

Tags: prisma2

i am on this challange since Monday... please help me? Check my models.

```
model User {
id String @id @default(cuid())
bookmarks Home[] @relation(name: "UserBookmarks")
}

model Home {
bookmarkedBy User? @relation(name: "UserBookmarks", fields: [userId], references: [id])
userId String?
}
```

This example is: ONE PERSON can have MULTIPLE Homes in their BOOKMARKS, ok?

My PATCH it works fine, check above.

```
const home = await prisma.home.update({ where: { id: "123" }, data: { userId: "my-user-id", }, });
```

When i see the content in PRISMA STUDIO... works fine... i have a list of Homes in bookmarks field. PERFECT.

BUT NOW... how i can DELETE a BOOKMARK in this CASE?

i tried eveything... but i cant understand how i can do that :-( I tried this code bellow:

```
const home = await prisma.home.delete({ where: { userId: "my-user-id", }, });
```

AND

```
const user = await prisma.user.delete({ where: { bookmarks: "my-home-id", }, });
```

In this case Above... appears this message:

```
{
"message": "\nInvalid prisma.home.delete() invocation:\n\n{\n where: {\n userId: 'cl3he5om60008you1geu5hbpa'\n ~~~~~~\n }\n}\n\nUnknown arg userId in where.userId for type HomeWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean id? Available args:\ntype HomeWhereUniqueInput {\n id?: String\n}\n\n"
}
```

HELP ME GUYS!

Thanks guys